# Getting authentication error on Inteliji Postgresql (Windows) with Docker-compose up

Tags: postgresql, docker, intellij-idea, docker-compose

I have a problem, I want to connect to PostgreSQL using docker and IntelliJ.
The docker .yml file works perfectly fine on my MacBook and I can also connect to PostgreSQL but not on my windows laptop. It always says, my password or user combination is wrong on Inteliji on my windows laptop.

.yml file

```
version: "3"
services:
  database:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    container_name: aic-database
    hostname: ${POSTGRES_HOSTNAME}
    restart: always
    ports:
      - ${DATABASE_PORT:-5432}:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_ENHANCED_COOKIE_PROTECTION: "true"
      networks:
        -database-network
```

and my env file

```
# Add anything that might need to be configured here

COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=AIC_GxTx

# Externally exposed ports (i.e. ports mapped on host system)
COLOR_SERVICE_PORT=4000
API_PORT=3000
DATABASE_PORT=5432
FRONTEND_PORT=8080
POSTGRES_HOSTNAME=localhostdock
POSTGRES_DB=postgres
POSTGRES_USER=aic_user
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=aic_pw
POSTGRES_DB=aic_db

DATA_PATH=./data.json
```

The funny thing is, I get total different output using docker-compose config command>

```
windows:
services:
  database:
    container_name: aic-database
    environment:
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_ENHANCED_COOKIE_PROTECTION: "true"
      POSTGRES_DB: aic_db
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: aic_pw
      POSTGRES_USER: aic_user
      networks: -database-network
    hostname: localhostdock
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    networks:
      default: null
    ports:
    - mode: ingress
      target: 5432
      published: 5432
      protocol: tcp
    restart: always
networks:
  default:
    name: aic_gxtx_default

and mac:

services:
  database:
    container_name: aic-database
    environment:
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_ENHANCED_COOKIE_PROTECTION: "true"
      POSTGRES_DB: aic_db
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: aic_pw
      POSTGRES_USER: aic_user
      networks: -database-network
    hostname: localhostdock
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    ports:
    - published: 5432
      target: 5432
    restart: always
version: '3'
```

Like I said this works perfectly fine on my MacBook but not on windows laptop. Can someone help me? Sitting here for like hours but still no clue what is wrong with this.

```
Inteliji error Message:

The specified database user/password combination is rejected: [28P01] FATAL: Passwort-Authentifizierung für Benutzer »aic_user« fehlgeschlagen (pgjdbc: autodetected server-encoding to be ISO-8859-1, if the message is not readable, please check database logs and/or host, port, dbname, user, password, pg_hba.conf)
```

Comment: Please quote the exact error message

Comment: HI, @jjanes i added it

Comment: Check the db server log file to see if there is more detail there.  Security messages sent to the unauthenticated client are intentionally vague.

Comment: Thanks fo the help! I found the solution!

Comment: Please post your solution here, so other users could find it faster